# Control in Visual Studio Gallery not seen in Visual Studio's Extensions and Updates dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-gallery

I published [a control](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6b05d344-d833-4785-aa8c-d05126713c89) to Visual Studio Gallery about two weeks ago.

The publication is live and people can download it from the site.

The issue is: I do not see my control in Visual Studio's Extensions and Updates dialog. I tried different searches and browsed through Most Recent list but it didn't help.

What else should be done to make my control appear in Visual Studio's Extensions and Updates dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control has started appearing in Visual Studio's Extensions and Updates dialog in about a month after publication.

So, there is only one solution in cases like this: wait. At least I do not know of any other solution.